# Turning PDF Macro into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlsm

I am trying to convert this code that instead of saving PDF copies it saves the individual sheets as Excel workbooks instead. I have tried changing the Export as fixed format to xlsm but it appears to have a run time error. Very new to this but any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub PDF()

 Dim xWs As Worksheet
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If xWs.Visible = True Then
   If xWs.Name <> "HOME" And xWs.Name <> "DATA" Then
       xWs.Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF P&L\" & Range("G1").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
   End If
  End If
 Next xWs
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.ExportAsFixedFormat` method doesn't support export to excel file formats [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat)

The action you're most likely looking for is `.move`. When not specified with where to move, this will create a new workbook with the moved sheet. You can then use `workbooks(Workbooks.count)` to access the latest created workbook. See example code below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

ActiveSheet.Move
Set wb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)

wb.SaveAs Filename:="yournamehere", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled 'etc...
```

Please note, when this is done to the last remaining or only sheet in the workbook, this will throw an error. For more info on the [`.move` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.attachment.move), see the link. For file formats to use [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.attachment.move).

Also, when moving a sheet, all the VBA code on the worksheet will be pulled across, but the modules related to the workbook won't. So attempting to save it as anything but xlsm when it has any code on it will result in a prompt or error.